# Function Undefined in Axios promise

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, axios

I have the following problem using ReactJs and Axios in an asp.net mvc app

```
var ForgotPasswordForm = React.createClass({
baseUrl:  "http://localhost:28804/",

getInitialState : function(){
    return{isDisabled:false, text: 'Email Password Reset Link', errorText:''}
},

changeText : function(newText){
    this.setState({text:newText})
},

resetText : function(){
    this.setState({text: "Reset Password"})
},

setErrorText : function(error)
{
    this.setState({errorText:error})
},

enableButton: function(){
    this.setState({isDisabled:true});
},

disableButton: function(){
    this.setState({isDisabled:false});
},

handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = this.refs.Email.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    if(!email)
    {  //TODO Show some sort of error message
        this.resetText();
        return;
    }
    var d = new FormData();
    d.append('Email', email);
    this.changeText('Please wait...');
    this.disableButton();
    console.log(d);
    var instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: this.baseUrl
    });
    instance.post('/Account/Login', d)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //I do not have a problem here
        }).catch(function(response){
           //this is where i always have an issue
         console.log(response);
         this.enableButton();
         this.resetText();
    });
    return;
},

render: function(){
    return (
        <form className="form-horizontal"   role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           //Omitted for brevity
        </form>
    );
}
});
   ReactDOM.render(<ForgotPasswordForm/>, document.getElementById('form-fgt-pwd'));
```

The problem is when the request fails (500 Internal Server Error on purpose), I get the following output in browser console

```
TypeError: this.enableButton is not a function
```

Please what Am i doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.catch` function `this` refers to global scope (in browser it is `window`), where there is not methods `enableButton`, `resetText`, these methods are part of `ForgotPasswordForm` object, you need set `this` for `catch` callback, you can do it with `.bind` method

```
.catch(function(response){
   this.enableButton();
   this.resetText();
}.bind(this)); // set this for callback that refers to ForgotPasswordForm Object
```